# Create a folder structure in a discussion board

Tags: content-type, folder, discussion-board

How can I create a folder structure in a discussion board? I have already tried this solution:

> 1) Create a new Site Content Type say called 'Thread Folder' based on the  Folder Content Type with the Parent Content Type as a
>   Discussion (Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Content Types)
>
> 2) Then, go into the Discussion List Settings and add the new content
>   type (Add from existing site content types)
>
> [source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/7bec66a8-a388-4980-adac-870bdbd3edb4/)

Then I create a new 'Thread Folder' and discussion in it. When click on Reply within this discussion, I cannot see item that represent root reply. How to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint OOTB Discussion Boards are not designed to work in a folder-like structure.  I assume you are trying to better categorize your discussion boards into topical groups.  Here are a few alternative routes you might try:

1) Use a Category column that you filter on.  Then you can use the various SharePoint filter web parts to "drill-down" to the posts in particular topics.

-or-

2) Use multiple discussion boards by topic.  Create a separate discussion board for each topic that you could then either simply list on a page to drill-down to or create a custom web part that grabs the counts, etc., from each board and aggregates them into a single view.

-or-

3) Use a third-party discussion board solution.  There are a number of options you could explore, from simply extending the existing discussion board functionality or adding completely new ones.