# Make "New Folder" command available missing in List settings

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, list, discussion-board, settings

I got tasked to create folders in a discussion board list library in SharePoint 2013. I noticed that the option to make a new folder was grayed out, so I went to the **list settings** >> **advanced settings** and tried to find the option "**Make "New Folder" command available**" which was available in my Document library settings. However I could not find this option in my List Settings.

How do I enable this option? Seeing that it might be disabled or missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be duplicate of the [Create a folder structure in a discussion board](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49144/create-a-folder-structure-in-a-discussion-board). Please have a look to this link and let me know whether this helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder structure in discussion boards. To do this, create a new Site Content Type say called 'Discussion Folder' based on the Folder Content Type with the Parent Content Type as a Discussion (Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Content Types)

Then, add the new content type (Add from existing site content types) in Discussion Boards List. You will have a new option called 'Discussion Folder' for that discussion board, by which you can create a folder. When the folder is created, simply go into that folder and add the discussions.